# Entity Framework Core 3.1 Load() Async Explicit Loading

Tags: c#, eager-loading, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have alot of EF Explicit Calls in my code that load data after to avoid EF Cartesian Products (as it slows my queries to a standstill)

```
var users = await dbContext.User.ToListAsync();
foreach (var user in users )
{
   await dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(b => b.VirtualProperty1).LoadAsync();
   await dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(b => b.VirtualProperty2).LoadAsync();
   await dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(b => b.VirtualCollection).LoadAsync();
}
```

Question is, can I drop `await` and do `await Task.WhenAll(AllAboveEagerLoadTasks)` ?

Comment: Your assumption that eager loading (`Include`) is the same as a cartesian product, is not correct. If `Include` is slow you can try to use [split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) in EF 5.

Comment: I know, but I'm using Azure Functions that's not yet ready for EF5 unfortunately.

Comment: My worry is will I get tracking exception

Comment: What is a tracking exception? Either with `Include` or `Load` the entities will be tracked. As for `WhenAll`, a context isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

As Gert mentioned in a comment and I've tested myself, the context is not thread safe, so can't laod entities in parallel unfortunately.
EF5 does offer a solution to SplitQueries.